# UINavigation bar all class?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am creating category for **UINavigationController** class.when i implement a method i couldnot see a any controls on navigation controller.i have tried..

**.h file**

## import

```
@interface UINavigationController (UINavigationControllFile)<UISearchBarDelegate>
-(void)setBarForCard;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "UINavigationController+UINavigationControllFile.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (UINavigationControllFile)
-(void)setBarForCard
{
    [self addNatigationItemsControls];
}
-(void)addNatigationItemsControls
{
    UIBarButtonItem *slideNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Slide"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(slideAction)];
    UIBarButtonItem *homeNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(homeAction)];
    UIBarButtonItem *categoryNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"category"
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(categoryAction)];
    UIBarButtonItem *searchNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Search"
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchAction)];

    UIBarButtonItem *orderHistory = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"History" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(orderhistoryAction)];
    UIBarButtonItem *checkOut = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CheckOut" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(checkOutAction)];

    NSArray *arrBarBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:slideNavigation,homeNavigation,categoryNavigation,searchNavigation, nil];

    NSArray *arrRBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:orderHistory,checkOut, nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arrRBtns;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = arrBarBtns;

}
-(void)homeAction
{

}

-(void)categoryAction
{

}

-(void)searchAction
{
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
    searchBar.delegate=self;
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 2,600, 24);
    [searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    UIView *barWrapper = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, searchBar.frame.size.width,24)];
    [barWrapper addSubview:searchBar];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = barWrapper;

}
-(void)orderhistoryAction
{
    //    OrdersViewController *ordersViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OrdersViewController"];
    //    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ordersViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void)checkOutAction
{

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"begin editing");

}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change ");

}



- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
    self.navigationItem.titleView =nil;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=nil;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=nil;
    // [self addNatigationItemsControls];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked %@",searchBar.text);
    NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search=%@",searchBar.text];
    NSLog(@"%@ ",temp);

}
-(void)slideAction
{


}

@end
```

and i implemented in another class but its not showing anything.

```
[self.navigationController setBarForCard];
```

tell me suggestion or give me some link?

is this correct way?

It should come for all view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply create a category for UIViewController

```
@interface UIViewController (UINavigationControllFile)
-(void) setBarForCard;



@implementation UIViewController (UINavigationControllFile)

-(void)setBarForCard
{
[self addNatigationItemsControls];
}
-(void)addNatigationItemsControls
 {
UIBarButtonItem *slideNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Slide"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(slideAction)];
UIBarButtonItem *homeNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(homeAction)];
UIBarButtonItem *categoryNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"category"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(categoryAction)];
UIBarButtonItem *searchNavigation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Search"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchAction)];

UIBarButtonItem *orderHistory = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"History" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(orderhistoryAction)];
UIBarButtonItem *checkOut = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CheckOut" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(checkOutAction)];

NSArray *arrBarBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:slideNavigation,homeNavigation,categoryNavigation,searchNavigation, nil];

NSArray *arrRBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:orderHistory,checkOut, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arrRBtns;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = arrBarBtns;
```

}

and then call it with [self setBarForCard]; from your ViewControllers..

Comment: thanks for the reply..if i press slide button it has to go another view controller but its not pushing another view controller